# Trying to compile the powershell script to exe with parameters

Tags: windows, powershell, exe

Im looking to convert my ps1 to exe. it has to be some kind of a compiler that can accept parameters since i would like this exe file to be a bit different some times.
for example i may have inside the script:

```
$var1 = 0
$password = 'blabla'
```

I would like to to make it possible to compile it with the possibility to change $var1 or $password WITHOUT making any change in the ps file.
is that possible?

**edit

After researching the subject, My goal was to make a template script and being able to manipulate the script and create more scripts from the template. in the template i had for examples variables of paths, usernames and so on. so i created a template script, and then another script which goes into the template script, reads it and then us the -replace method to replace what is needed and create a new script.
after that i used ps2exe script to compile it to exe

Comment: Why not just call the script?  Why does it need to be an exe?

Comment: If you pass a password via command line argument, every user will be able to see it in the process list. Just saying...

Comment: The Boss want it to be an EXE file that each user will have and it should have few builds. that why im not doing this as script

Comment: Seems like a code request but you may want to check out https://github.com/NicoNekoru/Ps1-and-Bat-to-EXE/blob/master/Convert%20Powershell%20to%20EXE.bat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Solution was:

1. Create Template script, whatever needed to be changed from the template mark as something like '@@@var1@@@'
2. Create another script to accept variables.
3. Get-content of the template script and use -repalce method to replace what is needed in the template script.
4. Compile the newly created script with Ps2Exe